# How to perform Image comparison in Appium?

Tags: appium

I need one help.
I am using Appium and I have a scenerio wherein I need to capture an image from the app under test, preserve that image as a baseline image and then capture another image from that app under test and then perform an image comparison between these two images.

Can anyone guide me how to do this please.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "search")
    public void eventsSearch(String data) throws InterruptedException, IOException {    
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        boolean status = false;

    //WebElement img = driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.ImageView");

      //take screen shot
    File screen = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                        .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);


    // for (String event : events) {
    driver.findElementById("your id")
            .sendKeys(data);
    driver.hideKeyboard();
    List<WebElement> list = driver
            .findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.TextView' and @index='1']");
    System.out.println(list.size());


    int i = 0;
    for (WebElement el : list) {
        String eventList = el.getText();
        System.out.println("events" + " " + eventList);
        if (eventList.equals("gg")) {
            status = true;
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }


    //capture image of searched contact icon
    List<WebElement > imageList = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView' and @index='0']");
    System.out.println(imageList.size());

    System.out.println(i);
    WebElement image = imageList.get(1);
    Point point = image.getLocation();

    //get element dimension
    int width = image.getSize().getWidth();
    int height = image.getSize().getHeight();

    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(screen);
    BufferedImage dest = img.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), width,
                                                                 height);
    ImageIO.write(dest, "png", screen);
    File file = new File("Menu.png");
    FileUtils.copyFile(screen, file);

    //verify images
    verifyImage("Menu.png", "Menu.png" );
    //Assert.assertTrue(status, "FAIL Event doesn't match" + data);
}

    @DataProvider(name = "search")
    public Object[][] searchData() {

    return new Object[][] { { "gg" } };
}


public void verifyImage(String image1, String image2) throws IOException{
    File fileInput = new File(image1);
    File fileOutPut = new File(image2);

    BufferedImage bufileInput = ImageIO.read(fileInput);
    DataBuffer dafileInput = bufileInput.getData().getDataBuffer();
    int sizefileInput = dafileInput.getSize();                     
    BufferedImage bufileOutPut = ImageIO.read(fileOutPut);
    DataBuffer dafileOutPut = bufileOutPut.getData().getDataBuffer();
    int sizefileOutPut = dafileOutPut.getSize();
    Boolean matchFlag = true;
    if(sizefileInput == sizefileOutPut) {                         
       for(int j=0; j<sizefileInput; j++) {
             if(dafileInput.getElem(j) != dafileOutPut.getElem(j)) {
                   matchFlag = false;
                   break;
             }
        }
    }
    else                            
       matchFlag = false;
    Assert.assertTrue(matchFlag, "Images are not same");    
 }
```

Comment: this is good. thanks. But I would need some further help where I need to compare 2 images and then if the images are different,then I need to state how much is their difference in terms of pixels or position. Can you please help me here.

Comment: post a new question then. I guess i answered whatever you were asking for.